# NSTimer when screen is locked

Tags: ios, background, nstimer

How do I keep the NSTimer persisting after the screen is locked in iOS 8? Every time I lock the screen it stops. I have tried putting it in an `NSRunLoop` to no luck.

Answer (score 1):

iOS always suspends NSTimers when the app is backgrounded. You can request some extra background time by using `UIApplication` `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` but be warned that it won't keep your timer going forever. Your best bet is to remember what time you are backgrounded in `applicationWillResignActive` and then check the current time when you are re-activated in `applicationDidBecomeActive` or `applicationWillEnterForeground`. Then you can calculate how much time passed when your app was inactive and do whatever is appropriate.

See the `UIApplication` docs here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html, particularly the section on "Managing Background Execution".